# Thread name not displaying in Thread.currentThread.Name

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the code below, in the second Console.WriteLine command, it fails to print the thread name. Can someone tell me why?

```
  public class Retailer
  {
    public void retailerFunc()
    {       
        ChickenFarm chicken = new ChickenFarm();

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {    
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Int32 p = chicken.getPrice();

            Console.WriteLine("Store{0} has everyday low price: ${1} each", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, p); // Thread.CurrentThread.Name prints thread name
        }    
    }

    public void chickenOnSale(Int32 p)
    {      
        // order chickens from chicken farm – send order into queue

        Console.WriteLine("Store{0} chickens are on sale: as low as ${1} each",        Thread.CurrentThread.Name, p); // Thread.CurrentThread.Name cannot print a name

    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you set the name somewhere?

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'll keep it in mind the next time :)

Comment: @AdrianNasui I'm not getting error, but getting the following output:
Store chickens are on sale: as low as $8 each
Store2 has everyday low price: $8 each
Store1 has everyday low price: $8 each
Store3 has everyday low price: $8 each
Store chickens are on sale: as low as $7 each

Comment: I'm sorry about the missing line breaks here..Just that each 'Store' begins on a new line, here you can see that the line with the 'sale' doesn't show the store number, whereas the lines with 'everyday low price' show the store number that has the lowprice

Comment: Check the answer it is what you need

Comment: @AdrianNasui In fact I need it to print which store has bagged the lowest price for sale

Comment: Well, you are asking for something else now.

Comment: @AdrianNasui In my code above, I'm priting the line with 'chickens are on sale' along with the store name(i.e the thread name).

Answer (score 3):

Has your application set the thread name?  The default value of [Thread.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name(v=vs.110).aspx) is null.  I'm guessing at the point chickenOnSale is called, the current thread does not have a name.

And for future reference, MSDN does have an article on [how to set a thread name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/581hfskb.aspx).  You can only set it once; any subsequent attempts to set the Thread.Name property result in an [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: this is not an answer rather a question, is it?

Comment: @AdrianNasui As of now yes, but if op replies for my comment as "no", then this is an answer indeed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is an answer :) OP will see this answer and then he will say "Oh so I need to set the name of thread, i didn't know that"

Comment: Why is this down voted? This is a correct, well, hint to op's question....

Comment: Can a question be an answer?  Apparently I have been watching too much Jeapordy!  :)  I have updated my question/answer to have more information.

Comment: It is an useful hint for me :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I am calling the thread only after setting it's name..

Comment: @SAGARKALBURGI Which thread calls `chickenOnSale`? and where did you set the name for that particular thread?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel There is another class called ChickenFarm that has an event called priceCut. The event handler for this is the chickenOnSale method. I am creating instances of ChickenFarm and Retailer classes in a separate class' main method, starting the ChickenFarm thread, registering the event handler and then starting the retailer threads

Comment: @AlG Thank you, but I am not requesting clarification.  I am expecting that the information following my question is the answer to the problem.